# Direct select multiple anchor points in Sketch 3

Tags: sketch-app, pen-tool, anchor-point

What is the most efficient way to select multiple anchor points in Sketch 3? I'm an Ai user and I want to instinctively toggle between the direct selection and pen tools and just click and drag - can someone provide me an equivalent process?

Below is how I currently select multiple anchors in Sketch 3.

Click object

Press enter

Hold cmd + option and click and drag anchor points

Adjust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to select multiple anchors is to utilize the multi-anchor icon on the right panel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

hold cmd + option and click and drag to select multiple anchor points. Hold option + shift and drag to deselect.

Comment: Thanks @LLong, that does cut having to click on multiple anchors..