# Direct select multiple points on multiple layers in Sketch 3

Tags: sketch-app, anchor-point

I know how to [direct select multiple points on a single layer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71711/direct-select-multiple-anchor-points-in-sketch-3), however how do you direct select multiple points comprised of **multiple layers?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is currently not possible in Sketch 3